# Slowly killing the grammar tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

In [this question](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1204/2594), the majority of voters opted for getting rid of the grammar tag, however there was [nobody in favour of a retagging event](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1207/2594). Instead, it was suggested that we retag slowly. So let’s do this:

Beginning now [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) should not be added to any new questions. The tag wiki is updated to reflect this. Most importantly, however, all 1303 existing questions with [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) have to be equipped with reasonable tags.

To this purpose, everybody is invited to go on moderate sprees to retag old questions tagged with [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) with the following considerations:

1. Do not blindly remove [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) and do nothing else. If we wanted this, we could make it happen automatically. Rather make sure to add all appropriate tags and remove further inappropriate tags. Of course, sometimes there is really nothing else to do except removing [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), but take care that this is really the case.
2. As a rough guideline, throttle retagging such that one of the first five questions on the home page is a recent one.
3. Also retag closed questions. If the question was closed for a reason other than *duplicate,* consider one of the following:

   - If you think that there is nothing of value on that question or its answers, do not retag, but take steps towards its deletion: If you have 2000 reputation, vote to delete. If the question has no positively scored or accepted answer and a score of one, downvote it (which will [trigger automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/255554)). Otherwise mention the question in chat.
   - Edit the question such that it can be reopened. Do not forget to cast a reopen vote.
4. Users without the edit privilege (1000 reputation) are also invited to participate.
5. If you are unsure how you should tag a question, mention it in chat. If you encounter general tagging issues, either mention them in chat or ask a Meta question about it.

This continues until there is no question left that is tagged [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) (maybe some odd exceptions). We can then proceed to burninate and blacklist the tag.

For now, I do not think we need a separate chatroom, but if you think that the main chat is overrun with posts regarding this, feel free to create one.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone ahead and blocked new uses of [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar):

[image: No grammar in German.]

If you like, I can burninate the tag after you've [cleaned up the edges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

Comment: *It'll also make closing these questions a lot less controversial* – I think you are confusing something here. We do not want to get rid of grammar questions; we just want to get rid of the tag (due to being overly broad and so on, see the linked Meta post). A new question tagged [grammar] should be retagged, not closed.

Comment: *there's no real excuse to use the tag if you got the warning* – [Except that for a considerable portion of users a tag warning is only a short flicker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278399/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Could you suggest copy for the popup (which can include a link to this meta question)? I can block the tag if y'all think it necessary, but we really need to have a sentence (or, at most, two) explaining what to do instead. Otherwise people will either abandon the edit or indiscriminately remove the tag.

Comment: *Could you suggest copy for the popup* – “[The grammar tag is deprecated and in the process of removal.](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1210) Instead, use a tag corresponding to the grammatical feature in question or use [tag:grammaticality] or [tag:grammar-identification] if applicable.”

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I've updated the answer to reflect your new blacklisted tag. Let me know when you are ready to burninate the remnants.

Comment: Burninate it!!!

Comment: @wogsland: Not yet. Many questions tagged *grammar* do not have reasonable tags (which is one of the reasons why we decided to kill this tag in the first place). If we burninate now, these will never be tagged properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe soeben eine [Frage zu einem Grammatik-Regelwerk](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34950/1487) gestellt. Diese Frage dreht sich sehr eindeutig um Grammatik, hat aber keine spezielle Ausprägung der Grammatik zum Inhalt, sondern gehandelt dieses Teilgebiet der Sprache als Ganzes. Ich denke, bei dieser Frage wäre das Etikett »grammar« sehr wohl angebracht, aber es ist leider nicht mehr möglich, dieses Etikett zu vergeben. Jetzt steht meine Frage, die sich sehr intensiv mit Grammatik beschäftigt, ganz ohne ein Grammatik-Etikett da.

Ich plädiere daher dafür, gerade für solche Fragen das »grammar«-Etikett durchaus noch zu erlauben.

Comment: Deine Antwort ist wohl [hier](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1204/2594) besser aufgehoben. Diese Frage dient der Umsetzung des Ergebnis der dortigen Abstimmung.

Comment: So oder so: Ja, für die Frage wäre dieses Tag angebracht, aber brauchen wir deshalb dieses Tag?