# Tags im Singular oder im Plural?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Bei den Tags gibt es bezgl. der Verwendung von Singular und Plural keine einheitliche Linie. Beispiel: *nouns* und *mass-noun, proper-noun, uncountable-noun*.

Ich schlage vor, dass Tags grundsätzlich in der Singularform angelegt werden (oder meinetwegen auch grundsätzlich in der Pluralform). Beide Varianten sollten jedenfalls nicht gleichzeitig als Tags auftauchen. Hier eine Liste der Pluralformen und eventueller Singularduplikate:

- abbreviations
- adjective-endings
- adjektivendungen
- adjectives / adjektiv
- adverbials
- adverb / adverbien / adverbs
- alternatives
- antonyms
- articles / artikel
- ausdrucke
- authorities
- auxiliary-verbs
- beginners
- brand-names
- cases
- children
- clauses
- cases
- comma / commata
- compounds
- conjunctions
- determiner / determiners
- dialect / dialects
- dialekt / dialekte
- fall / falle
- fragewoerter (frageworter)
- loanword / loanwords
- nuance / nuances
- orthografie / orthographie [hat zwar nicht damit tun, aber muss wirklich die "f"-Schreibweise als Tag vorhanden sein?]
- phrase / phrases
- prefix / prefixes
- suffix / suffixes
- unterschied / unterschiede
- valediction / valedictions

Ich schlage eine Bereinigungsaktion vor, bei der zumindest die Duplikate gelöscht werden.
Davon gibt es 12.

In einigen Beispielen wäre die Verwendung des Singulars auch aufgrund der Umlautthematik sinnvoll:

- *ausdruck* statt *ausdrucke*
- *fragewort* statt *frageworter*
- *fall* statt *falle*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich habe die Liste und zumindest die zweihundert größten Tags abgearbeitet. Bis auf die folgenden Ausnahmen ist jetzt alles Singular und nur Singular:

- Ich habe den Plural als einzige Form belassen, wenn er m. E. Missverständnissen oder Falschverwendungen vorbeugt, namentlich [numbers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers), [children](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children), [quotes](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes). Gleiches, wenn der Plural weit verbreiteter ist, z. B. [trivia](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia).
- Ich habe den Plural zusätzlich belassen, wenn er den Singular nicht als Substring enthält, sodass das Tag ggf. nicht vom Vorschlagsmechanismus gefunden wird, z. B.: [faelle](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faelle).
- Ich habe ein paar Tags nicht angerührt, bei denen ich mir nicht sicher bin, warum sie überhaupt existieren, namentlich [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) und [clauses](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clauses). Meta-Posts hierzu: [Vorschlag: Einstampfung von [standard-german] und [rules]](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1690/2594), [Brauchen wir [clauses]?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1691/2594)
- Bei [determiners](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/determiners) hält mich [ein Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378068/255554) davon ab, Synonyme umzukehren.

Ein weiter Vorteil, der mir dabei aufgefallen ist, ist übrigens, dass Englisch und Deutsch häufiger zusammenfallen, z. B. bei [synonym](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym).

Comment: Vielen Dank auch für diese mühevolle Arbeit! Nun gibt es noch *worterbucher* und *woerterbuecher* sowie *fragewoerter* im Plural.

Comment: *Nun gibt es noch* worterbucher *und* woerterbuecher *im Plural.* – Und jetzt nicht mehr.

Answer (score 1):

Das Hauptproblem bei Tags ist meiner Meinung nach nicht deren - vermutlich "historisch gewachsene" - Inkonsistenz, sondern dass sich so mancher Frager keine besondere Mühe mit einer prägnanten Auswahl gibt. So wird *grammar* noch gerne genutzt, obwohl nicht empfohlen, und *word-usage* wird auch sehr häufig verwendet (vielleicht, weil es dem Fragenden das weitere Klassifizieren spart?)

Ich habe gerade bei einer Frage mit dem einzigen Tag "grammatical-case" dieses ersetzt, weil es nicht einmal ein Randthema war. Das kann jeder mit Änderungsrecht, ab 10000 Reputation wird es aber bequemer, weil ein Knopf "Edit tags" angezeigt wird. Ich rufe nachdrücklich dazu auf, bei solchen Fragen, die man nur mit viel Mühe gefunden hat, die Tags zu prüfen und zu ergänzen oder zu ändern, damit sie in Zukunft leichter auffindbar sind.

Ohnehin habe ich den Eindruck, dass Tags bei vielen Benutzern nicht im Fokus stehen - es gibt nämlich immer noch erstaunlich viele, die nicht einmal eine ausführliche Beschreibung besitzen.

Wenn man den Namen eines Tags nicht in eckigen Klammern in die Suchzeile tippt, ist der Wortlaut sowieso ohne Bedeutung.

Meine Einschätzung: Eher kosmetischen Gewinnen steht reichlich (Moderatoren-) Arbeit gegenüber.

Comment: Bei den Tags liegt tatsächlich ein großer Wust vor. Es gibt zurzeit 305 Primärtags, die mit Fragen verknüpft sind. Es liegt auf der Hand, dass eine so große Zahl nicht sinnvoll sein kann. Mir ist klar, dass eine systematische Bereinigung nicht möglich ist - es würden dann möglicherweise Tags gelöscht, an denen das Herz einzelner Personen hängt, obwohl vielleicht nur wenige Fragen damit verknüpft sind. Mein Vorschlag soll auch den Moderatoren nicht dauerhaft Zusatzarbeit bescheren, sondern möchte nur einige "niedrig hängende Früchte ernten".

Comment: Die Löschung von 12 Duplikaten ist sicher nicht der große Durchbruch, aber besser als nichts.  Wenn  meine Rechte ausreichen würden, würde ich dies gerne übernehmen.

Comment: *So wird* grammar *noch gerne genutzt, obwohl nicht empfohlen* – Das kann nicht sein. Das Tag [grammar] [ist geblockt](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1216/2594) und kann nicht mehr für neue Fragen genutzt werden (oder bei Editierung alter Fragen beibehalten werden).

Comment: *Eher kosmetischen Gewinnen steht reichlich (Moderatoren-) Arbeit gegenüber.* – Das schlichte Umbenennen von Tags ist relativ einfach für uns Moderatoren, sofern wir eine Liste zum Abarbeiten haben. In den meisten Fällen dürfte es sich auf das Löschen und Flippen von Synonymen beschränken und wenn nicht, sollten die Synonyme auf jeden Fall angelegt werden. Wahrscheinlich habe ich mehr Zeit in diesen Kommentar verbraucht als das Ergebnis umzusetzen. Andererseits gestehe ich ein, dass der Gewinn wirklich gering ist.

Comment: @PaulFrost: *Wenn meine Rechte ausreichen würden, würde ich dies gerne übernehmen.* – Die meisten nötigen Aktionen sind nur für Moderatoren möglich oder bedeutend einfacher für Moderatoren. Außerdem können wir Tags umbenennen ohne die Hauptseite mit allen betroffenen Fragen zuzumüllen. Aber wie bereits gesagt: Es hilft durchaus, eine Liste zum Abarbeiten zu haben.