# Vorschlag: Einstampfung von [standard-german] und [rules]

Tags: discussion, tags

[standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) und [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) sind als Tags praktisch nutzlos, da sie über die Jahre praktisch beliebig genutzt wurden – ohne einen großen Zusammenhang zur Frage. Es gibt nur sehr wenige Fragen gemäß des Verwendungszwecks laut Tag-Wiki, nämlich darüber, woher Standards, Regeln, usw. rühren.

Ich schlage deshalb vor, dass wir:

- [language-regulation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-regulation) mit Synonymen [authority](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authority), [reglementierung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reglementierung), [sprach-instanz](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprach-instanz) erschaffen und auf alle passenden Fragen anwenden. Wir durchsuchen hierzu [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) und [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) nach geeigneten Fragen.
- [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) und [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) entfernen und blocken lassen, d. h. sie werden von allen Fragen entfernt und können nicht neu erschaffen werden.

Modus: Stimme diese Frage auf oder ab, um Deine Zustimmung oder Ablehnung zu signalisieren. Antworte, um Ergänzungen, Verbesserungen oder Gegenvorschläge vorzubringen.

---

#### Proposal: burninate [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) and [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules)

These Tags are basically useless, since they have been used pratically randomly over the years, i.e., without any meaningful relation to the question. Only few questions use them as described by the tag wiki and ask about the provenance of language rules and similar.

I thus propose that we:

- create [language-regulation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-regulation) with synonyms [authority](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authority), [reglementierung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reglementierung), [sprach-instanz](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprach-instanz) and apply it to all suitable questions, which we find particularly by searching [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) and [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules).
- have [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-german) and [rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) deleted and black-listed, i.e., they are removed from all questions and cannot be created again.

Modus: Up- or downvote this question to indicate your (dis)agreement. Write an answer for amendments, improvements, or counter-proposals.

Comment: Ich bin dafür und dankbar, wenn du dir die Arbeit machst.

Comment: What is the meaning of the suggested new tags? They seem rather diffuse to me, too too the degree I cannot come up with example questions for either

Comment: @planetmaker: The new tag (just one) would be for questions about the process, institutions, etc. that regulate the German language, i.e., what [standard-german] and [rules] should cover as per their tag wikis. An example question would be [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15246/2594). But admittedly there will be few questions on this.