# Brauchen wir [clauses]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Das Tag [clauses](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clauses) scheint mir ziemlich chaotisch genutzt zu werden. Ich vermute, dass das die Nutzung hauptsächlich dadurch motiviert ist, ob ein Analogon in der englischen Grammatik als *clause* bezeichnet wird. Dies ist aber nicht so einfach ins Deutsche übertragbar, da gewisse grammatikalische Konstrukte nicht existieren oder anders funktionieren. Ich wüsste daher z. B. nicht einmal, wie ich das Tag auf Deutsch bezeichnen sollte.

Wenn niemand einen besseren Vorschlag hat, würde ich daher alle Fragen in dem Tag durchgehen und umtaggen, sodass das Tag verschwindet. (Wenn jemand anderes dies machen bzw. dabei helfen möchte, beschwere ich mich auch nicht.)

Comment: I am now doing this. If anybody wants to help, just go through the questions in [tag:clauses] at a reasonable rate: Re-tag such that one of the first five questions on the home page is a recent one.

Answer (score 3):

Ich teile die Vermutung; mir fällt nur *Haupt- oder Nebensatz* ein, einen passenden Überbegriff habe ich nicht gefunden, da *Satzarten* anders verwendet wird und nur *Nebensatz* als Tag vorhanden ist.

Comment: Right now, there are also tags for [subordinate-clause], [relative-clause], and [main-clause]. (Es gibt Tags für [subordinate-clause], [relative-clause], und [main-clause].) These questions can presumably be retagged accordingly using those tags, if appropriate.

Comment: @V2Blast: The funny thing is that those more specific tags and the respective concepts have equivalents in the German language: *subordinate clause ↔ Nebensatz; relative clause ↔ Relativsatz; main clause ↔ Hauptsatz.* However, *clause* does not. *Satz* is just *sentence;* and while dictionaries offer translations like *Halbsatz* or *Gliedsatz* for *clause,* these do not capture everything named *clause* in English, in particular some things the questions tagged [clause] are about.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Interesting... I love the nuances of languages :)

Comment: @V2Blast: `nitpicking mode on` English 1 day, 2 days = German 1 Tag, 2 **Tage** (e at the end and German pronunciation). But: English 1 tag, 2 tags = German 1 Tag, 2 **Tags** (s at the end and English pronunciation) (or 1 Etikett/Schild, 2 Etiketten/Schilder but in this context Tag/Tags is the better choice)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Interesting! I feel like I meant to write "Tags" originally but mixed the two up...